Ghost stock in magento 2
im working on magento 2.4.7 and been experimenting on the MSI features. i have a very straightforward simple product that has a 1 saleable quantity even though the sources are all 0. i tried to check the inventory_reservation table and everything should have been offset already. also tried to do reindex and full compile multiple times. anyone has an idea what still needs to be checked?

still have 1 saleable quantity

inventory_reservation is 0

